# Nette framework Url not working on localhost

Tags: php, url, localhost, nette

The PHP Nette framework, Url is not working on localhost. On the live server it is working fine but when I installed it on localhost from the latest backup from hosting server it does not work.

My `.htaccess` file is as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

My Localhost URL on Wamp which the home page is working properly

```
http://localhost/ongoingclients/www/www/
```

But other urls are not working.

Comment: I also tried with apache server mod-rewrite url setting

Comment: Update grammar and coding format for readability

Comment: Show full Apache zone file, show contents of /www folder, show nette router and we will see.

Answer (score 1):

what does it mean that it is not working? It shows 404 from apache?

try to check that

- `mod_rewrite` in apache is enabled
- `AllowOverride` in apache vhost settings is set to `All`

Comment: It shows 200 ok, also i checked with both mod_rewrite & AllowOverride of Apache httpd & vhost. Still not working

Comment: In PHP Nette framework Url not working on localhost.
On the live server It is working fine, I installed on localhost from the latest backup from hosting server. Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resolved by .htaccess of rule RewriteBase

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ongoingclients/www/www/

    # prevents files starting with dot to be viewed by browser
    RewriteRule /\.|^\. - [F]

    # front controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
```

Got success, thank you.